# how to make this git alias?

Tags: git, alias

I use this command to export all files in specify commit(s)

```
git archive --output=export.zip --format=zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only COMMIT1 COMMIT2)
```

I want to make an alias so I dont need type this long command everytime.

I tried:

```
git config --global alias.he "archive --output=\"$1\" --format=zip HEAD \$(git diff --name-only \"$2\" \"$3\")
```

However, when I run `git he 1.zip COMMIT1 COMMIT2`, it prompts

```
error: unknown option `name-only'
```

Could anyone help me for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Aliases don't generally take positional parameters. A better way to do this would be to write a short script - assuming you want to use the syntax you mention (`git he 1.zip COMMIT1 COMMIT2`), name the script `git-he` and put it somewhere in your path (e.g. `${HOME}/bin` if you are the only expected user, or `/usr/local/bin` for broader accessibility):

```
#!/bin/sh
git archive --output="$1" --format=zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only "$2" "$3")
```

For subcommands it doesn't recognize, `git` will search your path for a script named `git-<command>`. It would be a good idea to put some sanity checking on the arguments in, and make sure to `chmod +x <path>/<to>/git-he`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a shell alias for this. I have several aliases defined in my bash profile.

```
alias gs='git status '
alias ga='git add '
alias gb='git branch '
alias gc='git commit'
alias gd='git diff'
alias go='git checkout '
```

I mostly just use `gs` instead of `git status`. But that should give you an idea.

Comment: I suggest not doing this. git st etc is pretty much standard

Answer (score 0):

Change your double quotes for the command itself to single quotes, like so:

```
git config --global alias.he "archive --output='$1' --format=zip HEAD \$(git diff --name-only '$2' '$3')
```

No need to escape single quotes within double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Just open you terminal and type

```
pico ~/.gitconfig
```

and paste this under your credentials

```
[alias]
    ci = commit
    cm = commit -am
    br = branch
    newbr = checkout -b
    delbr = branch -d
    showbr = for k in `git branch|sed s/^..//`;do echo -e `git log -1 --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%ci %Cblue%cr%Creset" "$k" --`\\t"$k";done|sort
    co = checkout
    df = diff
    dfc = diff --staged
    changes=diff --name-status -r
    diffstat=diff --stat -r
    lg = log --graph --oneline --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset - %C(yellow)%s%Creset %C(green)<%an<%Creset' --abbrev-commit
    new = !sh -c 'git log $1@{1}..$1@{0} "$@"'
    llog = log --date=local
    fork = remote add -f
```

And when ever you want to add or remove aliases just edit this.